# How to read *all* input from stdin?

Tags: streams, input, unix

The answers given to this [similar question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3425/2464) won't do, because those solutions read only one line from `stdin`.

I want to read *all* available lines, pretty much in the way that standard Unix programs like `cat`, `grep`, `wc`, etc. do.

EDIT: I'd prefer a "pure-*Mathematica*" solution, if possible.

Comment: You don't have to accept yet. I'll be surprised if there's a better solution, but let's wait a bit anyway. People are more likely to look at a question if it isn't marked as answered.

Comment: @Szabolcs: done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not aware of any pure Mathematica solution.  The usual way is to read from the stream

```
stream = OpenRead["!cat"]
```

You can do this directly with any read functions, such as `Import`, `Read`, `ReadString`, `ReadList`, etc.  For example,

```
Import["!cat", "String"]
```

I spent a considerable amount of time searching for a simpler solution, and while I cannot rule out that it exists, I wasn't able to find it.  You can also read from `StartProcess["cat"]` (it's readable as a stream), but that's basically the same thing.

These solutions do read *all* lines on OS X. [wolframscript](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/program/wolframscript.html) (new in 11) can read from stdin without extra help, but it's buggy: it only reads the data available in the buffer, and then it exists.  [It doesn't wait for new data like `cat` does.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/132023/line-by-line-processing-with-a-wolframscript#comment356680_132177)