# How do I reliably read from stdin using wolframscript?

Tags: import, scripting, streams, input

I am trying to direct a stream of data to a `wls` script in a command line environment. Wolframscript provides the `$ScriptInputString` symbol to read `stdin`. However, when the input is large, no input is apparently read.

How do I read from the standard input for large sizes?

---

Minimal (not) working example:

```
for i in $(seq 0 $SIZE); do echo $i; done | wolframscript -print -c \$ScriptInputString
```

When `$SIZE=100000` (one hundred thousand), outputs all integers from `0` to `1000000`. When `$SIZE=1000000` (one million), outputs nothing.

`$Version` is `11.3.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The implementation of `$ScriptInputString` in `wolframscript` is buggy. I have [found](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/133597/48942)  that providing `!cat` to an import function (`ReadString`, `Import`, ...) is a more stable way of reading from `stdin`.

When using `wolframscript`, this approach only works in cases where `$ScriptImportString` doesn't, presumably because the stream is already consumed otherwise.

A combination of the two works for both small and large inputs in my tests:

```
stdin = $ScriptInputString <> Import["!cat","String"]
```