# How to read input stream with no newlines?

Tags: scripting, input, streams

I have a script named `stdout.wl`:

```
While[True, Pause[0.001]; WriteString[OutputStream["stdout", 1], RandomInteger[]//ToString//(#<>"\r\n")&]]
```

I have another script named `stdin.wl`:

```
While[True, Pause[0.001]; Print[InputString[]]]
```

Run them in commandline:

```bash
WolframKernel -script stdout.wl | WolframKernel -script stdin.wl
```

It works well, the terminal prints those random integers generated from the first script to the second one.

Now I want to remove the `\r\n`s from the `stdout.wl`:

```
While[True, Pause[0.001]; WriteString[OutputStream["stdout", 1], RandomInteger[]//ToString]]
```

I wonder how should I change the `stdin.wl` to make this work again:

```
While[True, Pause[0.001]; Print[(*somefunction[]*)]]
```

I've tried the answers under

- [Reading from STDIN, or: how to pipe data into Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3425/reading-from-stdin-or-how-to-pipe-data-into-mathematica)
- [How to read *all* input from stdin?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/133593/how-to-read-all-input-from-stdin)

But none of them works.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `StringTrim[...]` or `StringReplace[..., "\r\n" -> ""]`?

Comment: Which version of MMA are you running? I am running MMA 12.1 under Windows 10. Here your code works flawless, with and without the "//(#<>"\r\n")&"

Comment: Hi @flinty, The Problem is given what is output from `stdout.wl`, I need to read them using `stdin.wl`. Is not about  reading those `\r\n` and remove them later.

Comment: Hi @DanielHuber, On windows 10, did you run `wolfram.exe -script stdout.wl | wolfram.exe -script stdin.wl` instead? Running `WolframKernel.exe` will open up a GUI window which is not desired.

Comment: Here _MMA 12.0_, Linux x86. The first script prints out the integers, the second prints nothing (no error).

Comment: Use [http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RecordSeparators.html] is postprocessing step using chunks of the stream in [http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReadList.html].

Comment: Hi @anderstood, I was asking to add some function in the `(*somefunction[]*)` comment so it can print the output of stdout.wl

Comment: @kenkangxgwe I had understood. I was just confirming the behaviour. Have you tried Steffen's suggestion?

Comment: @anderstood, Yes I tried, but ReadList with Record and RecordSeparators didn't help.

Comment: @SteffenJaeschke, using ReadList with Record and RecordSeparators didn't help.